# Heisenberg Uncertainty relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

The derivation of the uncertainty principle says that for any 2 observables 
$A$ and $B $, we act $$ A+i\lambda B $$   on a normalized state and demand the norm of the new state be greater than or equal to zero.

Why are we doing this? For example, if we look at the Cauchy Schwartz Principle, what we are doing is basically saying, given 2 vectors, I can project the first of them onto the second and there will exist a perpendicular component (which may or may not be zero.)

So, is there something in the derivation that I'm not seeing?

P.S -  I understand that,given the axioms, this is a perfectly valid thing to do. But what I don't see is the motivation.

Comment: I don't really understand your question - in my mind, the "standard" derivation of the uncertainty relation doesn't contain anything of the form $A+\mathrm{i}\lambda B$ and there doesn't need to be a "motivation" for any particular step in a proof if it leads to the correct result. Please provide better context for what you're asking.

Comment: I was talking about the generalized uncertainty principle.(for any 2 observables). You are right when you say there is no need for a motivation for any step in a proof. But the fact that you choose a particular direction must have some reason(or so I would like to believe.)  Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical motivation is that you get a quadratic form

$$\langle\psi|(A-i\lambda B)(A+i\lambda B)|\psi\rangle\geq0$$

assuming that $A$ and $B$ are Hermitean, and thus

$$\langle\psi|(A^2+i\lambda[A,B]+\lambda^2 B^2)|\psi\rangle\geq0$$

or

$$\langle\psi|A^2|\psi\rangle+\lambda\langle\psi|i[A,B]|\psi\rangle+\lambda^2 \langle\psi|B^2|\psi\rangle\geq0$$

This is a quadratic polynomial in the variable $\lambda$ and if it is to be positive, its coefficients have to lead to a negative discriminant.

$$D=(\langle\psi|i[A,B]|\psi\rangle)^2-4\langle\psi|A^2|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|B^2|\psi\rangle\leq 0$$

which is the Heisenberg uncertainty relation.